# AVAudioPlayer is releasing before playing?

Tags: xcode, audio, release, avfoundation

I'm making a `soundboard` app and I use this code to play `mp3` files:

```
-(IBAction)playSound 
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mysound" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    theAudio.delegate=self;
    [theAudio play];
    [theAudio release];
}
```

When I include `[theAudio release];` the sound doesn't play. If I take it out it plays but I don't want to have memory leaks. How can I fix this?

It would be very helpful if you could include whatever code I need to add. I'm new to programming (besides TrueBasic I've used in school) so I'm unfamiliar with Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

wait til the audio finishes via a delegate to release the audio. I believe there are a number of posts exactly like this on the site if you search, they will have the specific delegate code.

Answer (score 0):

This is only because you use local variable. so theAudio will released immediately.
You should define it as class member and assignment it here. so when this function finished, it still work too.

Comment: And it's sad there have a lot of sample make this mistake too, you are mis-leaded.